# Surround each date select with their own div in CakePHP

Tags: html, cakephp, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, web

I am using CakePHP v2.3.6 and have just downloaded Bootsrap 3.0.0 RC1. I wish to place the 3 selector inputs used for the date of birth next to each other. The way to do assign a width to inputs in BS3 is to put each input inside its own div with a col class (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes). However this code:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input(
'dob', 
array(
    'label' => array(
        'text' => 'Date Of Birth',
    ),
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'form-group required col-lg-4',
    ),
    'separator' => ' ',
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
)
);
?>
```

Overrides the div surrounding all the inputs rather than placing one around each select individually like so:

```
<div class="form-group required col-lg-4">
    <label for="UserDobDay">Date Of Birth</label>
    <select name="data[User][dob][day]" class="form-control" id="UserDobDay">...</select>
    <select name="data[User][dob][month]" class="form-control" id="UserDobMonth">...</select>
    <select name="data[User][dob][year]" class="form-control" id="UserDobYear">...</select>
</div>
```

How do I surround all 3 inputs with their own divs?

Answer (score 1):

With the FormHelper::input() method you can use these options between, separator, after to wrap the three date selects:

```
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array(
    'label' => 'Date Of Birth',
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'form-group required col-lg-4',
    ),
    'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
    'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
    'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
    'between' => '<div>',
    'separator' => '</div><div>',
    'after' => '</div>',
));
```

To see all options available take a look here: http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-FormHelper.html#_input